# What does this strange Makefile target ".PHONY" mean?

Tags: make

In this https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/Makefile
there are targets with a dot in front of them. What is this convention for ?

```
.PHONY: all
all: build

.PHONY: build
build:
    GOBIN=$(BINDIR) $(GO) install $(GOFLAGS) -tags '$(TAGS)' -ldflags '$(LDFLAGS)' k8s.io/helm/cmd/...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The special rule `.PHONY` is used to specify that the target is not a file. Common uses are `clean` and `all`. This way it won't conflict if you have files named `clean` or `all`.

Here is a [link to a section on this topic](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) in the GNU make manual